# Swift string comparison failing

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

So I just started "learning" swift for a project I'm doing and I've come across a pretty interesting scenario and I can't figure out why it's happening.

So the basic gist of my project is as follows: I have a SQLite Database of state laws which is basically an excel table with 4 columns; section, law, note, tag. And all my app does is pre-load this database on to the users phone or the simulator and allow the user to search for a law based on the tags. Multiple laws can have the same tag which in this case I would display a preview of all the laws with such tag and let the user pick one.

Here is my ViewController that handles this tag search:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import SQLite


class UISearchController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    var database2: Connection!
    var table2: Table?
    var lawTemp: String?
    let section = Expression<String>("section")
    let law = Expression<String>("law")
    let note = Expression<String>("note")
    let tag = Expression<String>("tag")

    @IBAction func queryTable(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            print("The chosen tag was: " + String(tagChosen.text!))
            let laws = try self.database2.prepare(self.table2!)
            print("CHECKPOINT 2")
            for row in laws {
                print(String(row[self.tag]) == String(tagChosen.text!))
                print("because the current law tag is: " + String(row[self.tag]))
                    //print(row[Expression<String>("law")])
                    lawTemp = row[Expression<String>("law")]
            }
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
        print("QUERY DONE")

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tagChosen: UITextField!


    @IBAction func sendText(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
        {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = String(describing: lawTemp)
            //controller.recipients = [phoneNumber.text!]
            controller.messageComposeDelegate =   self
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
        //... handle sms screen actions
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }

    let tags = [String](arrayLiteral: "Public lands", "Definitions","Natural Resources","Powers","Risk Assesment","Land Disposition","Board Duties")

    //MARK: - Picker View Data Sources and Delegates

    func numberOfComponents(in tags: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return tags.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
             tagChosen.text = tags[row]
        return tags[row]
    }
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            let laws = try self.database2.prepare(self.table2!)
            for lawl in laws {
                print("SECTION: " + lawl[self.section])
                print("TAG: " + lawl[self.tag])
                print("NOTE: " + lawl[self.note] + "\n -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                print("LAW: " + lawl[self.law])
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        tagChosen.inputView = pickerView
    }
    //override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //let dest = segue.destination
        //let tableViewController  = dest as! UILawTableViewController!
        //tableViewController.table3 = table2
        //tableViewController.database3 = database2
    //}
}
```

and here is what I get when I pick "Natural Resources" as my `tagChosen`, this is the console output:

```
The chosen tag was: Natural Resources
CHECKPOINT 2
false
because the current law tag is:
Definitions

false
because the current law tag is:
Public lands

false
because the current law tag is:
Natural Resources

false
because the current law tag is:
Natural Resources

false
because the current law tag is:
Natural Resources

false
because the current law tag is:
Powers

false
because the current law tag is:
Board Duties

QUERY DONE
```

It shoud really be printing out `true` for 3 of those checks. And ideally I would put those 3 rows where there was a match into an array and use that to show the user the possible laws. Can anyone help? Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: did you try String.compare(anotherString : String) ?

Comment: Could it be that `String(row[self.tag])` has a trailing newline? – Try `print(String(row[self.tag]).debugDescription`

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't ever prefix UI or any other SDK provided class prefixes. It's better if you have your own conversion for the classes which you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove invisible chars as sugegsted by Martin :

```
String(tagChosen.text!).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == String(row[self.tag])).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Just edit your answer because you're comparing the same the `row[self.tag]` to itself, when it should be compared to `tagChosen.text!`:)